# set tab bar to transparent but can't bring it back to default style

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

I was able to set my tabBar to transparent with the code below but I don't know how to bring it back to default style. Please help if you can and thank you very much!

```
tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundColor = .clear
    tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
    tabBarController?.tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before setting your tab bar to clear color save all the properties

```
let originalBackgroundImage = tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundImage
let originalshadowImage = tabBarController?.tabBar.shadowImage
let originalbackgroundColor = tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundColor
```

then change to clear color

```
tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundColor = .clear
tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
tabBarController?.tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Finally when you need it back

```
 tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundColor = originalbackgroundColor
 tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundImage = originalBackgroundImage
 tabBarController?.tabBar.shadowImage = originalshadowImage
```

Finally call `layoutIfNeeded` on tabBar
Hope it helps

Comment: Holy cow! I realize sometimes I just think too much. Thank you very much!

Comment: @kevin-vu : hehehehehe :) Happens to everyone buddy :) Am glad you solved it